# redux: how to deal with an API that returns null for some things?

Tags: redux, react-redux

If I am interacting with an API that returns null for some objects that may or may not have value, how can I reconcile that with the reducers?

example: app state

```
{
    foo: {
       foo1: null,
       foo2: {
           bar: null,
           bar2: null
       }
    }
}
```

but the server, when things are null, returns this:

```
{
    foo: null
}
```

but it can return the full state when things have value:

```
{
    foo: {
       foo1: "somefoo,
       foo2: {
           bar: "barvalue,
           bar2: 27
       }
    }
}
```

the problem I ham having is that my reducers are trying to load the state from the return value from the server, and then my components are trying to read from a null object and it is failing.

EDIT: the reducer and the component would look like this... so the component is trying to read some nested json, which may come back as unnreadable because the parent object is null. In this case I know I could hack up a solution that checks if the object is null and inserts my predefined initial state...

BUT...my actual example is a bigger json object than this and I know it will change in the future, so I need a solution that is not so fragile and cumbersome as adding a ton of logic here to check to make sure that every object down the nested like is not null.

```
var updateSettings = (settings = jsonShape, action) => {
  swtich (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_SETTINGS: 
      return Object.assign({}), settings, {
        foo2: {
          ...settings.foo2,
          bar: action.newBar
        }
      }
    }
  }

const Component = ({ settings }) => {
  return (
    <div>{ settings.foo2.bar }</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please show me the Redux code, action dispatcher and reducer.

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha I added the details about the reducers

Comment: I think lodash has a function to perform deep checks on objects, maybe that would be helpful. I think that the place you really want to do these checks is in your components, which should be able to handle some case where various levels of your object are null. A simple example being if (foo && (foo.foo1 || foo.foo2) && foo.foo2.blah){ do something }

Comment: I could handle it in the component or in the reducer, but the problem remains the same in that there is a confusing mess of stuff to sort through and it will have extremely poor readability, there must be a better solution somewhere

Comment: Would not applying a state change when `null` comes back be an option? Why does the the API return `null` in the first place? If this data is unusable, maybe you can just not apply it at all. If you need default values, then I think an object fall back would be best. `var foo = Object.assign({}, myResponse || {}, myDefaultState);`